# Exception Code: c000001d when running at python (opencv)

Tags: python, opencv

When I run the face detection sample in the OpenCV Python examples, it always crashes when the code enter

```
rects = cascade.detectMultiScale(img, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=4, minSize=(30, 30), flags = cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE)
```

I use Visual Studio, and there it also shows the exception code: `c000001d`

I have attached the problem signature below.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    4f84a6c8
  Fault Module Name:    cv2.pyd
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   509430c8
  Exception Code:   c000001d
  Exception Offset: 004d60dc
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Answer (score 0):

`c000001d` is an illegal instruction.  The most common reason for that is corruption to the binary file, like a DLL, or in this case `cv2.pyd`.

There are several ways it could have got corrupted.  You might have transferred or copied it as a text file, for example.  Another common issue is running a 64-bit code file on 32-bit hardware, or maybe a 64-bit binary with a 32-bit python, or any commbination of the above.

It could also be that you are running code on a wildly different instruction set or code file format, for example copying code from ARM and expecting it to run on Intel, or from Linux (ELF) to Windows (PE COFF).

Comment: thanks for the reply..so how could i solve this problem, or check whether my dll work under my machine?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by downgrading opencv 2.4.3 to 2.4.2.

I'm not saying opencv2.4.3 has problem, it can work at the other pc, but not my pc.

OpenCV 2.4.2 requires tbb_debug.dll but OpenCV 2.4.3 does not. I think that is the difference between 2.4.2 and 2.4.3. Maybe the trick lies in tbb_debug.dll files.

Comment: Does one PC have an Intel chipset and the other AMD?  tbb is Intel's "Thread Building Blocks" and can cause issues on AMD.